# adehabitatHR locoh.k orphan holes

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I am trying to optimise the k parameter using `AdehabitatHR LoCoH.k.area` and it stops running when the topology is such that it can't produce a polygon.  Message is:

> rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon
>   for hole at index 12.

I have done a number of successful single runs using LoCoH.k with only a few not running due to orphan holes.

Is it possible to keep `LoCoH.k.area` looping through the k values specified in the vector even if the one prior produces an orphan hole?

Thanks, Janine

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to SE, could you provide your data and code, which throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You cant wrap `LoCoH.k.area` function in `tryCatch`. E.g. the function with `krange = 5:9`  argument throws:

> Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(oobj) : 
>   rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon
>   for hole at index 6

Please see the code below:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
data(puechabonsp)
locs <- puechabonsp$relocs

## The call below throws an error
## LoCoH.k.area(locs[, 1], krange = 5:9)

pdf()
y <- sapply(5:9, function(x) tryCatch(
  expr = cbind(LoCoH.k.area(locs[, 1], krange = x), k = x), 
  error = function(e){}, 
  finally = NULL))

dev.off()
do.call(rbind, y)
```

Output:

```
     Brock    Calou     Chou     Jean k
1 25.21552 38.61693 83.37389 80.97771 8
2 27.37161 39.10789 86.45349 83.44156 9
```

Comment: Thanks Artem.  I am off on Leave for a month so will try your suggestion when I return.  Many thanks again.